# Vertically center divs inside div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, centering

I am a beginner and trying to to my own wordpress theme from scratch (using bootstrap, stripping away everything and adding my own). Now I have got stuck on an annoying problem.

I have a div containing 3 smaller divs which gonna be menu-items as images. I have gotten the 3 to be horizontally centered in comparison to the outer div but not vertically.

I have set the inner divs to be as high as the outer but im not able to get the inner contents to also be vertically centered.

This is my code:
HTML

```css
#menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
}

div.menu_item {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}

div.menu_item img {
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 15px;
  clear: both;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 4px 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div class="menu_item">
    <p>
      <a title="" href="myimg"><img alt="" src="/myimg.png" width="125" height="125" /></a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu_item">
    <p>
      <a title="" href="myimg"><img alt="" src="/myimg.png" width="125" height="125" </a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu_item">
    <p>
      <a title="" href="myimg"><img alt="" src="/myimg.png" width="125" height="125" </a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Im aware of that this might be very messy and almost certain some things arent needed and could be stripped away but I have tried to figure it out for myself and this is what Ive came to this far.

Screenshots of it is here:
outer div
[image: outer div]

one of the inner divs
[image: one of the inner divs]

The first shows the outer div, the second shows one of the inner divs.

UPDATE: Solution was fiddling around with flexbox and it was quite easy even for me. Also, I tried to strip away as much as I could from the CSS and still have the same result and apparently almost no code is required.

This is my CSS now

```
 #menu
{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:60%;
    height:300px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

This makes the content of #menu to be centered both vertically and horizontally.

Comment: Duplucate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
div.menu_item
{
    width: X%; /*change to display: table; if you're targeting IE8 or greater, requires !DOCTYPE */
    margin: 0 auto;
    ...
}
```

The `width` just must be less than the outer `div`, I put `X` to represent the percentage.

The same can be done with `height`:

```
...
height: X%;
...
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but I tried it and it doesnt do what i want, it doesnt affect the contents of the inner div.

Comment: What if you apply that to the contents of the `div` themselves?

Comment: Hmm i will try but if the divs didnt align vertically i dont think the contents will either.